# Select distinct row or particular value row if not distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have a table where as below, I want to get records by id which have value b if value b is not there then value b. I have a date volumn associated in the table by which I can use order by date.

I tried to post an image of screen from mobile it failed attach.
Also could not post sql which i tried as it is officially not allowed here.

My attempt to explain the question is below

```
Persid.      Value.    Date
1                 a
1                 a
1                 a
2                 b
2                 a
2                 a
```

Expected result

```
1           a.       Latest date
2           b        any date
```

I have tried using group by on id and value columns to get count but I am not able to understand how to use that count to filter out records.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select id, value, date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by persid
                                order by value desc, date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This gets the latest date for any value.  Note that the `value desc` is so "b" appears before "a".  If your values are not ordered alphabetically, then you can use a `case` or other mechanism to set the proper sort order.

Comment: This seemed to work when i changed value to asc order. I already have a complex query with partition by on different table its result should be filtered so basically its a partition over partition : d. Thank you